# What emulation mode for an epson printer is best?

Tags: printing, emulation

I'm looking for a color duplex printer for Ubuntu. My favourites are Epson B-310N and Brother HL 4050CDN. The latter should be work with linux, but I'd prefer the first one, because printing costs are cheaper.

The epson printer has "Epson ESC/P Raster", "PCL3", and "Epson ESC/P2" emulation. Can I use the printer with one of those emulations under linux? Were there any restrictions (like unusable duplex)?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard PCL3 should work without problems under linux, including duplex (I have one Samsung printer in this setup, because using SPL over the net didn't work right, it's B/W but duplex works fine).

But I don't know if the PCL3 support of this printer is really good or have some flaws. Trying before buying is really the best option when you bought from Epson.